# WordPress : How to change Ordering 'Ajax Load More' Plugin

Tags: ajax, plugins, wordpress

'Ajax Load More' Plugin has installed on my website, i want to change Ordering

there is `spacial`field in `wp_posts` Table On `DB`

But I can't how to set in on my posts

```
<option value="spacial" selected="selected">VIP (default)</option>
<option value="date">Date</option>
```

changed on :

```
 plugins / ajax-load-more / admin / shortcode-builder / shortcode-builder.php
```

So it is :

```
<div class="inner half">
   <label class="full"><?php _e('Order By', 'ajax-load-more'); ?>:</label>
       <option value="spacial" selected="selected">VIP (default)</option>
   <select class="alm_element" name="post-orderby" id="post-orderby">
       <option value="date">Date</option>
       <option value="title">Title</option>
       <option value="name">Name (slug)</option>
       <option value="menu_order">Menu Order</option>
       <option value="author">Author</option>
       <option value="ID">ID</option>
       <option value="comment_count">Comment Count</option>
       <option value="modified">Modified</option>
       <option value="meta_value_num">meta_value_num</option>                   
   </select>
</div>
```

But Nothing has changed and posts don't sort as i want

Shortcode Output on `Admin Panel > Ajax Load More > Shortcode Builde` :

```
[ajax_load_more post_type="post" orderby="spacial"]
```

Where should i put 'shortcode-builder' Code ?

------------------- Updata -------------------

You mean Admin Panel > Apearacne > Editor > main Page (Home page)

I can found :

```
echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more category__not_in=1 '.$query.'  button_label="More Posts" orderby="title" order="DESC"  posts_per_page="20" ]');
```

When i change `orderby` To `spacial` it doesn't works

Also I try :

```
<?php 
    $cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $category = $cat->slug;

    if (!empty ($category))
        $query .= ' category="'.$category.'" ';
    if (isset ($_GET["province"]) && !empty($_GET["province"]))
        $query .= ' meta_key="province" meta_value="'.$_GET["province"].'" ';
    if (isset ($_GET["city"]) && !empty($_GET["city"]))
        $query .= ' meta_key="city" meta_value="'.$_GET["city"].'" ';
    $query .= ' ORDER BY SPACIAL DESC';
    echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more category__not_in=1 '.$query.'  button_label="More Posts" posts_per_page="20" ]');

?>
```

Comment: I am not sure what did you mean by change order, but you can put `shortcode-builder` action/filter hook into active theme/child theme's `functions.php file`.

Comment: @Milap I am beginner at WP, can you explain me more ?

Answer (score 4):

You can only order by custom field value not a field in the wp.posts table (I believe). 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

If spacial was a custom field.

```
[ajax_load_more post_type="post" orderby="meta_value" meta_key="spacial"]
```

Comment: it sort by Title and some fields in wp_posts table, so how it do this ?

Comment: You can't. You would need to create a custom query using the WordPress WPDB class. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb  Then pass the results of this custom query to Ajax Load More using the `post__in` shortcode parameter.

Comment: Post Updated, Please Check it, Thank you

Comment: can i use multiple query in postmeta table usig alm ?